# Where to put properties files when dealing with internationalization?

Tags: java, internationalization

I'm trying to make a internationalization in my program and I found this simple example how to use it:

```
package tests;

import java.util.*;

public class I18NSample {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        String language;
        String country;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            language = new String("en");
            country = new String("US");
        } else {
            language = new String(args[0]);
            country = new String(args[1]);
        }

        Locale currentLocale;
        ResourceBundle messages;

        currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);

        messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
        System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell"));
    }
}
```

but every time I compile the code i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US
```

My files are named MessagesBundle_en_US.properties and MessagesBundle_es_ES.properties and are placed in the same package as I18NSample class, so it should work, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the root of the classpath because it use by default non package.

Otherwise change:

```
messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
```

to

```
messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("tests.MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
```

to make it work with the bundle inside of the directory/package of your class.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely need to read about classpaths, because to this point I tried to avoid this topic